# How to count "points" from all users with a role in a database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord, discord.js

Okay, I am currently trying to create a "gang" system with MongoDB. I have a point system already setup and want to create "gangs". I want one feature of a gang to be is it has a global "wealth" where it takes all the users with a role of that gang and adds their points together and stores it in the DB.

How would I get all users with a specific role and then check all their points and add them together.

My guess would be running a `` Points.find({serverID: message.guild.id}).sort([[`points`, `descending`] ``

But, how would I get all the members in a role so I can pull their points together.

My Points Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const pointsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userID: String,
    userName: String,
    serverID: String,
    points: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Points", pointsSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to get every member who has a role. You can do this easily with the [`Role.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members) property. You can then use [`Collection.map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) to map all the users by their IDs (so you can find their point documents), and [`Collection.array()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=array) to convert the collection to an array.

Then, you can use the mongoose [`$in`](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/the-mongoose-in-operator-1015) operator to find every document which has a `userID` that is included within the array.

Lastly, you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to add together all the points.

```js
// <role> is a placeholder for the role object
const members = <role>.members.map((m) => m.id).array();

Points.find(
  { serverID: message.guild.id, userID: { $in: members } },
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!result) console.log('There are no users with this role');
    console.log(
      `Point Total: ${result.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.points, 0)}`
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: It says that ```const members = args.members.map((m) => m.id).array();``` map is unidentified at args.members.map

Comment: I am trying to grab the role off of this: ```let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === `${args}`);```

Why won't it work? I just need to put the args into the role. It is stating it's undefined

Comment: `args` is an array. You need to compare it to a string.

Comment: Same think: Cannot read property of 'map' of undefined guilds.

Comment: If I try running it with ```message.guild.roles.cache.get(role).members.map...```
then it says can not get members of undefined. How is it undefined.

Comment: How did you define your `role` variable? The parameter should be a role ID.

Comment: ```let role = args.join(' ')``` my args is just the mention of the role so for example "!gang @test" it pulls the ID from the role that was tagged

Comment: No, it will return `<@&roleID>`. Replace the `roles` variable with just `message.mentions.roles.first()`

Comment: ```TypeError: role.members.map(...).array is not a function``` ??

Comment: My bad, I forgot `Collect.map()` already returns an array. Remove the `array()` part.